# List ClusterServiceVersions using K8S Go client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm trying to use the [K8S Go client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to list the `ClusterServiceVersion`s.
It could be enough to have the raw response body.

I've tried this:

```golang
data, err := clientset.RESTClient().Get().Namespace(namespace).
    Resource("ClusterServiceVersions").
    DoRaw(context.TODO())

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

fmt.Printf("%v", string(data))
```

But it returns the following error:

```
panic: the server could not find the requested resource (get ClusterServiceVersions.meta.k8s.io)
```

How do I specify to use the `operators.coreos.com` group?

Looking at [some existing code](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/blob/master/pkg/api/client/clientset/versioned/typed/operators/v1alpha1/clusterserviceversion.go#L90) I've also tried to add

```golang
VersionedParams(&v1.ListOptions{}, scheme.ParameterCodec)
```

But it result in this other error:

```
panic: v1.ListOptions is not suitable for converting to "meta.k8s.io/v1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do a raw request using the `AbsPath()` method.

```golang
path := fmt.Sprintf("/apis/operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1/namespaces/%s/clusterserviceversions", namespace)

data, err := clientset.RESTClient().Get().
    AbsPath(path).
    DoRaw(ctx)
```

Also notice that if you want to define `clientset` using the interface (`kubernetes.Interface`) instead of the concrete type (`*kubernetes.Clientset`) the method `clientset.RESTClient()` is not directly accessible, but you can use the following one:

```
clientset.Discovery().RESTClient()
```